# How to convert Oracle Next_Day Function to Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Can someone please let me know how to convert the Oracle NEXT_DAY Function to Postgres?

Converted an Oracle Stored Procedure to Postgres function and there is an error while executing the Postgres function in PGADMIN IV as its throwing an error at the below sql ?

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'Thursday') FROM DUAL;
```

How can I convert the above Oracle SQL which uses the Oracle Function NEXT_DAY to Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this:

```
SELECT 'TOMORROW'::date + ( 4 + 7 - extract ( dow FROM 'TOMORROW'::date))::int%7;
```

4 is Thursdays ordinal number

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect! Thanks for your time.,

Answer (score 3):

Improving the above answer, I came up with this in case some random date is used. I am new to PostgreSQL, so it may not be best and optimised.

```
SELECT '9-APR-2020'::date + COALESCE(NULLIF((4 + 7 - EXTRACT(dow FROM '9-APR-2020'::date))::int%7 , 0 ), 7);
```

Comment: A CTE could simplify that a little. and rather than special-casing "today" just add 1 to the input  `WITH a AS ( select '9-APR-2020'::date +1 as d )  SELECT  a.d  + ( 4 + 7 - extract ( dow FROM a.d))::int%7 FROM a;`

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Jasen for the logic.

I have created the `next_day` function using his answer.

```
-- converts weekday name to dow i.e. SUN -> 0, MON -> 1, etc.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weekdayname_to_dow(weekdayname VARCHAR) RETURNS INT AS
$$
SELECT
  CASE UPPER(weekdayname)
    WHEN 'SUN'
      THEN 0
    WHEN 'MON'
      THEN 1
    WHEN 'TUE'
      THEN 2
    WHEN 'WED'
      THEN 3
    WHEN 'THU'
      THEN 4
    WHEN 'FRI'
      THEN 5
    WHEN 'SAT'
      THEN 6
  END AS ret_val
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

-- gets a date and finds the date of next desired weekday.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_day(date_input DATE, weekdayname VARCHAR) RETURNS DATE AS
$$
SELECT $1::DATE + COALESCE(NULLIF((7 + weekdayname_to_dow($2) - EXTRACT(DOW FROM $1::DATE))::INT % 7, 0), 7) AS result
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```